# Is it possible to create RSA key-pair using AWS Java SDK?

Tags: java, amazon-ec2

I am trying to find out whether it is possible to generate RSA key-pair using the Amazon Web-Services API. The generated key-pair is ECDSA and so far I could not find any way to change that. Sure I have the option to create key-pair on the client-side and pass that to the instance creation request. I will most likely do that if generation of RSA key-pairs is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

AWS EC2 API does have a method for RSA key-pair Generation. Check [CreateKeyPair](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_CreateKeyPair.html). And Java SDK also supports this method. Check [createKeyPair](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/ec2/AmazonEC2.html#createKeyPair(com.amazonaws.services.ec2.model.CreateKeyPairRequest)).

Comment: Yes, I know of that method. However, when I use it, I get an ECDSA key. That is the precisely the reason why I asked the question. :) It would be good if I could specify the type of the key (DSA, RSA, ECDSA), but it seems like it is not possible.